# Android, RecyclerView: Correct view is being loaded but inflated at wrong position

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I am making an app that playes music files on your phone. It lists all songs with their artist name, the song name and the album cover (if available) inside a recycler view.

Everything worked fine until I was trying to load the album covers. 
While at the beginning (before I scrolled) everything looks fine, after some scrolling, the covers start to appear where they shouldnt. So say I have just seen the album cover of song X and then after some scrolling the same cover of song X appears next to song y. 
This is especially wierd since it does load the album name and everything else correctly. It just confuses the bitmaps. This is how I initialize my recycler view:

```
    private async Task InitRecView()
    {
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {

             // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:

             LinearLayout lnBg = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.background_recView);

             mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(GetSortedListWithAllSongs(), this, dbSeekObj, seekObj, mAudioManager, this, lnBg);

             // Get our RecyclerView layout:
             mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

             // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
             mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

             mRecyclerView.SetItemViewCacheSize(15);
             mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
             mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheQuality = DrawingCacheQuality.High;

             mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
             mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
         });
    }
```

This is my Adapter, where I retrieve the data (issue could be occuring in "SetContentAsync()"

```
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.CardView, parent, false);
        PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, mp3Obj, act, reader, db, seekObj, audioManager, lnBg, ctx);
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;

        SetContent(vh, position);
    }

    private async void SetContent(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
    {
        await SetContentAsync(vh, position);
    }



    private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
    {
        string SongName = "";
        string ArtistName = "";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        byte[] data = null;

        try
        {
            reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
        }
        catch { }


        await Task.Run(() => // cause problems with the reload
        {
            SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
            ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

            data = reader.GetEmbeddedPicture();
            if (data != null)
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
        });

        ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
            vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)
                CutImageIntoForm(bitmap, vh); // Set as the musical note button
            }

        });


    }
```

And this is the viewholder, where nothing much happens but to init the views:

```
    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Activity act, MediaMetadataRetriever reader, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, AudioManager audioManager, LinearLayout lnBg, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        // Locate and cache view references:
        SongName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        AristName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        lnContainer = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_cardview);
        CoverArt = itemView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.musical_note);

        this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
        this.act = act;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.db = db;
        this.seekObj = seekObj;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.audioManager = audioManager;
        this.lnBg = lnBg;


        lnContainer.Click += delegate
        {
            int pos = AdapterPosition;
            ClickEvent(pos, AristName.Text, SongName.Text, CoverArt, lnBg);
        };
    }
```

If anyone could help me out here. Why is my recycler view confusing the bitmaps and puts them into the wrong layouts and / or doubles them?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I have noticed that the reoccurance of the same items happens always within the same interval. For me, every 24th item contains the image the item 24 position before that item had. Also I read that it is because the recycler view is recycler said view but what I do not understand is how to find out if an item is recycled and when it is, just use new data...

Answer (score 0):

Since you use async method it's no wonder it shows old data. Create `clear` method in the viewHolder and call it in onViewRecycledMethod:

```
public class TextRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextRecyclerAdapter.TextViewHolder> {
    ...        
    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull TextViewHolder holder) {
        //clear your view here
        holder.clear();
    }
    ....

    public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {    
        ...
        public void clear(){
            //clear your view here
            _textView.setText("");
        }

        private TextView _textView;
        ...    
    }
```

**Update**
This also may happen because old data from async call comes later then new one. You need to cancel old requests in on recycled by using cancellation token.

Comment: Hello an thanks so much. I found the override method OnViewRecycled, however, the holder doesnt seem to have a "clear" property... Would you happen to know the equivalent in C#?

Comment: @InnomotionMedia of course it does not have it, you have to implement it yourself, since holder is view specific.

Comment: @InnomotionMedia I added one more important fact to my answer.

Comment: @InnomotionMedia see the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Comment: @InnomotionMedia In brief you need to create CancellationToken and before setting values to your UI you should check if it was cancelled and do not apply changes to your view.